# Runge-Kutta 4 method for complex differential equations in python

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, equation-solving, runge-kutta

I am trying to solve the equations of motion of a complicated system using the RK4- method in python, but I am not very familiar with this method and need help in fixing my code. The differential equations are:

First part of equations:

[image: First part of equations]

next part of equations:

[image: next part of equations]

The code I have written is:

```
import numpy as np

p = 7.850
A = (0.01) ** 2
m1 = 1
m3 = 1
g = 9.81

r2 = 1

r3 = 1

r1 = 1

rcm = r1

r = 4 * r2

m2 = 1


def equations(t,y):
    theta, phi1, phi2, x1, w1, p1 = y

    f0 = x1
    f1 = w1
    f2 = p1  # Corrected the variable name to p1

    # Calculate f4 and f5 separately
    f4 = ((m1 * r2 * rcm * x1**2 * np.sin(theta + phi1)) - (m3 * r3 * (r-r2) * p1**2 * np.sin(phi2 - phi1)) - (g * m1 * r2 * np.sin(phi1)) + (g * m2 * ((r/2)-r2) * np.sin(phi1)) + (g * m3 * (r-r2) * np.sin(phi1)) - (m1 * r2 * rcm * np.cos(theta + phi1) * f3) + (m3 * r3 * (r-r2) * np.cos(phi2-phi1) * f5))/((m1 * r2**2))
    f5 = ((m3 * r3 * (r-r2) * np.sin(phi2 - phi1) * w1**2) + (g * m3 * r3 * np.sin(phi2)) + (m3 * r3 * (r-r2) * np.cos(phi2-phi1)))/(m3 * r3**2)

    # Calculate f3 using the previously calculated f4 and f5
    f3 = ((m1 * r2 * rcm * w1**2 * np.sin(theta + phi1)) + (g * m1 * rcm * np.sin(theta)) - (m1 * r2 * rcm * np.cos(theta + phi1) * f4))/(m1 * r2**2)
    theta1, phi1, phi2, x1, w1, p1 = y
    return np.array([f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5])


def RK4(t, y, h, f):
    theta, phi1, phi2, x1, w1, p1 = y
    # Runge Kutta standard calculations
    k1 = f(t, y)
    k2 = f(t + h/2, y + h/2 * k1)
    k3 = f(t + h/2, y + h/2 * k2)
    k4 = f(t + h, y + h * k3)

    return 1/6 * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)

def main():
    
     # Specify time interval and number of domain subintervals
    t0 = 0
    T = 100
    n = 10000
    # initial conditions
    y0 = [np.pi - np.arccos((2 - 1.5) / r2), np.arccos((2 - 1.5) / r2), np.arcsin(1.5/(r-r2)), 0, 0, 0]

    # Domain discretization
    t_n = np.linspace(t0, T, n)
    y_n = [np.array(y0)]

    # Step size
    h = (T - t0) / n

    while t_n[-1] < T:
        # Keep going until T is reached.
        # Store numerical solutions into y_n
        y_n.append(y_n[-1] + h * RK4(t_n[-1], y_n[-1], h, equations))
        t_n = np.append(t_n, t_n[-1] + h)

    print(y_n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this code, i recieve the output:

```
[array([2.0943951 , 1.04719755, 0.52359878, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        ])]
```

This looks like it is returning the initial conditions meaning the system stays constant and that's not the outcome i am looking for. Any help and/ or alternative methods will be greatly appreciated as i would also like to simulate the system. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be convenient to see the equation(s) you're trying to simulate. I'm also wondering why your output consists of only one element? Did you post only the last one?

Comment: The equations are in the links, but I will post the pictures shortly, and no I posted the entire code I used and that is the only output I received after running the code.

Comment: I tried out your code to see that indeed the output has only one element. This is because you're initializing `t_n` but then in the while loop treating it as if it is empty at the beginning and adding elements to `t_n`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't take a look at the links. Thought, they were the Runge-Kutta equations.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you are saying, I am really new in python and solving equations numerically, how can I that?

Comment: `t_n = np.linspace(t0, T, n)` is creating all values for `t`. I.e. all elements are precreated if you want. But with `while t_n[-1] < T:` and `t_n = np.append(t_n, t_n[-1] + h)` you are assuming that the array is empty at the beginning and you are adding elements on the fly.

Comment: E.g. you could use something like `for t_i in t_n: y_n.append(y_n[-1] + h * RK4(t_i, y_n[-1], h, equations))` instead of your while loop. You will btw find that your Runge-Kutta function has some errors in it because e.g. `f3` is referenced before assignment.

Comment: Even worse, as `t_n[-1]` is exactly `T`, the loop condition is false from the start, the loop is not entered, and the original unchanged initial state gets printed. For a short solution, initialize `t_n=[t0]`, do not use `linspace`.

Comment: Thank you for the help @lord_haffi and Lutz with the new modifications you have suggested, I keep getting the error that f3 or f4 or f5 is referenced before the assignment no matter which order I order them in. How can i modify the equations such that this error does not appear?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I tried your suggestion using a simpler set of differential equations, and did work very well and solved it as normal so thank you for that, but it does not work for my code which I think its because all my differential equations depend on each other.

Comment: It would be easier to cut into the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equations at an earlier point, assemble the equations into a large linear system and use a linear solver to get the second derivatives all-at-once. In a 3x3 system it makes not much difference if the system is solved via some factorization or manually via Cramer, in higher dimension factorization (Gauss-PLU, QR, etc) is more economic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sympy or the CAS of your choice to get the many derivatives in the Euler-Lagrange system automatically correct.

Most mechanical Lagrange functions in conservative systems are separable into kinetic and potential term

```
L(x,Dx) = 1/2*Dx^T*M(x)*Dx - V(x),   D=d/dt the time derivative
```

The dynamical equations can then be written as

```
p = M(x)*Dx
Dp = 1/2*grad_x(Dx^T*M(x)*Dx)-grad_x V(x)
```

Using the impulse variable `p` leads to the Hamilton formalism with `Dx = M(x)\p`. The aim here however is to use the second derivatives, that is, the first derivatives as components of the state. To that aim take the time derivative of the first equation to get

```
Dp = M1(x;Dx)*Dx + M(x)*DDx
```

where `M1(x;Dx)` is the directional derivative of the matrix-valued function `M(x)` in direction `Dx`. To compare

```
(M1(x;Dx)*Dx)[i] = M(x)[i,j;k]*Dx[j]*Dx[k]
grad_x(Dx^T*M(x)*Dx)[i] = M(x)[j,k;i]*Dx[j]*D[k]
```

with the semi-colon separating matrix position indices and derivative direction indices.

Then

```
M(x)*DDx = -grad_x V(x) + 1/2*grad_x(Dx^T*M(x)*Dx) - M1(x;Dx)*Dx
```

is now a linear system for the second derivatives `DDx` that can be solved with methods of the linear algebra module.

So if you can identify `M(x)` and `V(x)` from your given Lagrangian, you can step over the manual calculation of the derivatives and implement the ODE system systematically.

Comment: I have already tried using that approach, but I decided to go with a simpler set of equations and once I more comfortable with python and numerical solvers, I will then attempt more complex systems. Thanks for help, it really helped me understand better.

Comment: If `M(x)` is not diagonal, like it happens with coupled mechanical constructs from the double pendulum onwards, then a naive approch will lead to circular dependencies. One can only break them by treating the system of coupled equations with general methods for such systems. Solution formulas can exist, like the Cramer rule, but they become quickly very large and expensive, relative to a procedural approach. This can look like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70236831/3088138, where I used the state to contain impulse variables instead of velocities. The position curves are the same for both.